# Notebook app for terminal

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js

I'm currently enrolled in a node.js course. The first app we have done in the course was a terminal notebook. It appends objects to a json-file.

Example call on the terminal:

```
node notebook.js add Second "Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor."
```

Example structure json-file:

```
[{
  "title": "First",
  "timestamp": 1481534161237,
  "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."
}, {
  "title": "Second",
  "timestamp": 1481534192437,
  "body": "Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor."
}]
```

Then the objects can be displayed, listed or removed.

The basic structure was done together with the trainer. Afterward I added the validation part and an additional property "timestamp". "timestamp" is mainly for listing the notes sorted in ascending order. Furthermore I wrote a function for creating a formatted date (based on the timestamp).

**notebook.js** (the "main" file):

```
    // ---- Assignments -----------
    const fs = require('fs');
    const notes = require('./notes.js');

    var args = process.argv;
    var errorReport = "\nSomething has gone wrong.";
    var maxLengthTitle = 150;
    var maxLengthBody = 1000;

    var command = args[2];
    var title = args[3];
    var body = args[4];

    // ---- Validation -----------
    if (['add', 'list', 'read', 'remove'].indexOf(command) === -1) {
       errorReport += `\nParam 1: Expected "add" or "list" or "read" or "remove".
       "${command}" found.`;
    }

    if (command) {
        if (!title && command !== 'list') {
           command = "";
           errorReport += `\nParam 2: Expected string. "undefined" found.`;
        } else if (title && title.length > maxLengthTitle) {
          command = "";
          errorReport +=
      `\nParam 2: Maximal length of title is ${maxLengthTitle} chars.`;
    }
    }

    if (!body || typeof body !== 'string') {
      body = '-';
    } else if (body.length > maxLengthBody) {
        command = "";
        errorReport += `\nParam 3: Length of given second parameter is ${body.length}
        Maximal valid length is ${maxLengthBody} chars.`;
    }
    // -------------------------------------------

    console.log('\n ----- NOTEBOOK ----- ');

    // ---- Reacting to the user input -----------
    if (command === 'add') {
       var note = notes.addNote(title, body);

       if (note) {
          console.log(`Note '${title}' has been added.`)
       } else {
          console.log(`Adding note has failed.'`)
       }
    } else if (command === 'list') {
       var allNotes = notes.getAll();

       allNotes.sort((a, b) => {
          return a - b;
       });

       for (let i = 0; i < allNotes.length; i++) {
          console.log('\n' + notes
           .createFormattedDate(allNotes[i]['timestamp']) + '\n' + allNotes[i]['title'] + '\n' + allNotes[i]['body']);
       }
    } else if (command === 'read') {
       var title = notes.readNote(title);

       console.log(`Title is : ${title} !`);
    } else if (command === 'remove') {
       notes.removeNote(title);

       console.log(`Note '${title}' has been removed.`)
    } else {
       console.log(errorReport);
    }
    // ----------------------------------------

    console.log('\n -------------------- \n');
```

**notes.js** (containing the module with the actual functions):

```
const fs = require('fs');

var fetchNotes = () => {
  try {
    var notesString = fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');
    return JSON.parse(notesString);
  } catch (e) {
    return [];
  }
};

var saveNotes = (notes) => {
  fs.writeFileSync('notes-data.json', JSON.stringify(notes));
}

var addNote = (title, body) => {
  var notes = fetchNotes();
  var note = {
    title: title.trim(),
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    body: body.trim()
  };

  notes.push(note);
  saveNotes(notes);

  return note;
}

var readNote = (title) => {
  var notes = fetchNotes();

  var ret = notes.filter((note) => {
    return note.title === title;
  });

  return ret[0] ? ret[0].title + '\n' + ret[0].body : '';
}

var getAll = () => {
  return fetchNotes();
}

var getNote = (title) => {
  console.log('Get single node: ', title);
}

var removeNote = (title) => {
  var notes = fetchNotes();
  var newNotes = notes.filter((note) => note.title !== title);

  fs.writeFileSync('notes-data.json', JSON.stringify(notes));
}

var createFormattedDate = (timestamp) => {
  var date = new Date(timestamp);
  var ret = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + date.getFullYear() + ', ' + ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

  return ret;
}

module.exports = {
  addNote,
  getAll,
  getNote,
  removeNote,
  readNote,
  createFormattedDate
}
```

It all works but "notebook.js" seems rather messy to me. How could it be better structured? What other improvements could be done?

I guess there a tasks which could be accomplished less awkward then I have done, especially concerning the formatted-date function.

Was it a good choice to use a date value for sorting the records? Or would another data type be more appropriate??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- One of the things a course should teach you is to take care when you decide what should be `const`, and what should not be `const`. Example of what ought to be `const` are `maxLengthTitle` and `maxLengthBody`
- Moving `process.argv` to `args` is sugar, it makes the lines 10 to 12 easier to read. However, in this case, I would have foregone the move and just use process.argv in lines 10 to 12. The code would be 1 line shorter, and not harder to read.
- You would get extra points if you could derive  'Expected "add" or "list" or "read" or "remove".' from the array you declared just prior to that with `['add', 'list', 'read', 'remove']`
- I would not clear `command` if there is an error, I would just make the first if after --reacting to the user input -- `if( errorReport ){` and go from there. I would also future proof that variable and call it `output` or `feedback`
- I am wondering about typeof body !== 'string', what case are you covering there?
- Run your code thru jshint.com, you have a few missing semicolons, some accessors that could use dot notation, and an unused library in notebook.js
- Read up on model view controller (MVC), your controller code (especially for command 'list', is doing far too much, in essence your code should read

  ```
  if(command == "list"){
    var allNotes = notes.getAll();
    console.log( formatNotes( allNotes );
   }
  ```

  and then drop the mic
- Finally, this drives me nuts:

  ```
  var getAll = () => {
    return fetchNotes();
  }
  ```

  Fat arrow syntax is meant for inline functions, please just use

  ```
  function getAll(){
    ..
  }
  ```

Comment: Awesome answer. Helped me to understand arrow functions. As inline function it makes perfect sense that they always got the this of the current context. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The idea with typeof body !== 'string' : In case someone has given another data type (e.g. number) then it wouldn't be empty. So it continuees with the next if-else. It would try to access the length property. This would cause an exception because most data types does not have that property.

Comment: for the last bullet, how about `const getAll = fetchNotes`?